# regex ruby for rack-ssl-enforcer

Tags: ruby, regex

With this regexp:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :only => %r{^\/[a-z][a-z]+\/users/sign_in}, :strict => true

^\/[a-z][a-z]+\/users/sign_in
```

It's valid for:

```
/en/users/sign_in
/es/users/sign_in
/de/users/sign_in
/fr/users/sign_in
```

I would like to add a valid regexp for urls like:

```
/en-us/users/sign_in
/en/users/sign_in
/en-ca/users/sign_in
/zh-cn/users/sign_in
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an optional non-capturing group:

```
^/[a-z]{2}(?:-[a-z]{2})?/users/sign_in
```

Note: this restricts the country/lang codes to two characters. Change to `{2,}` if you want "two or more".